# How to count numbers in nearby cell with criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use Google Sheets to count the hours that my staff works every month. So far I have this:

[image]

In the left, my staff write their name and the account of hours they have worked that day. What I would like to do is to count the total hours each one of them has worked in the right hours-column. Is this possible? So far I only know that you can count how many times they have worked using `countif`, but that does not count the account of hours they have worked.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to give the query() function a try.
Assuming your data is in the range A1:D, try:

```
=query(A1:B; "select A, sum(B) where A <>'' group by A"; 1)
```

Note: depending on your locale you may have to change the semi-colons with comma's..

This is a one formula solution that will update when new rows are added. I hope that helps ?

Comment: Thanks! It works, but is there any way I can get rid of the "sum" in front of hours?

Comment: Yes, try: =query(A1:B; "select A, sum(B) where A <>'' group by A label sum(B) 'Hours' "; 1)